# Complex analysis prelim inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a holomorphic function on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ such that $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leq \frac{1}{1-\lvert z\rvert}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{D}$. Show that $\lvert f'(z)\rvert \leq \frac{4}{(1-\lvert z\rvert)^2}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{D}$.

The only inequality that I know that looks sort of like this is the Schwarz-Pick lemma, but we do not have that $f(z)$ has range contained in $\mathbb{D}$, so we can not use this as is. I have also tried using the Cauchy Integral formula to estimate \begin{equation}\lvert f'(z)\rvert =\lvert \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\lvert \zeta\rvert =r}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^2}d\zeta\rvert\end{equation} for $1>r>\lvert z\rvert$, but I ended up with something going to infinity on the RHS as I tried to take $r\to1$.
At this point I'm sort of throwing ideas at a wall, so if someone could give me a small hint, that would be excellent.